# Passing an array to client side function using Google apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

### HTML

```
<html>
<table>

 <tr>
  <select id="Ultra"  onchange="getForm()">
          <option value="0.0">1</option>
          <option value="1.0">2</option>
          <option value="2.0">3</option>
          <option value="3.0">4</option>
      </select>
   </tr>
<tr>

<td id="demo">
 <script>

function getForm()
            {
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunction).myFuncti();
         }
        function myFunction(arry) 
        { 
           var x = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
           for(i=0;i<arry.length;++i)
           {
             if(arry[i][0] == x)
             {
              var a = arry[i][1];
              }
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;

             }

       }


   </script>
   </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</html>
```

I have created a Drop down menu using select , after that I was calling client side function `getForm()`.  In that function I was calling server side function `myFuncti()` using `google.script.run` class and this will return an array which I was passing to a client side function `myfunction()` as an parameter.

If use `Logger.log()`, the server side function is returning array values successfully !!

It's an 2D array .. Am I passing it in right way to `myFunction()` ?

If you couldn't understand anything in the question please add a comment I will reply

Comment: you explain what is working but not where the problem occurs, what isn't working and what error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: In the Executin Transcipit , It was showing successfully executed !!

Comment: I think , The problem is , The server side function returns an array i.e, myFuncti() and I am passing this 2D array directly into the client side function  myFunction(arr)

Comment: So what isn't working for you?  According to the documentation, you should be able to return an array from your server side function and use it as you are doing. Do you see an error in the Javascript Console on the client side?

Comment: Can I debugg Javascript code in Script Editor ? May I know about process. Sorry to bother you

Comment: You can debug the Javascript code as you would with any other client side Javascript, using the Developer Tools in your brower. In Google Chrome, find this under "Tools" -> "Javascript Console", or find the equivalent under your chosen browser.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK), This is the error it was showing

Comment: That error might not be related to the problem, you'll need to watch the console while you try submitting the form, use console.log() to log to the Javascript console from your client side function.  Use my answer below, which addresses your original question, as a starting point.  Other questions with details on how to debug client side Javascript should be present on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the code needs to look like, note the use of console.log() to debug on the client side (CTRL-SHFT-I usually opens the developers console window in the browser):

**index.html**

```
<div>
  <select id="Ultra" onchange="getForm()">
    <option value="1.0">1</option>
    <option value="2.0">2</option>
    <option value="3.0">3</option>
    <option value="4.0">4</option>
  </select>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script>

function getForm() {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunction).myFuncti();
}

function myFunction(arry) {

  var x = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
  var y = parseInt(x, 10);
  var i = 0;
  var a;

  console.log('x (string) = ' + x);
  console.log('y (number) = ' + y);  
  console.log(arry);

  for (; i < arry.length; i++) {

    a = arry[i];

    console.log('a = ' + a);

    if (a === y) {

      console.log('a === y');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(form) {

  return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function myFuncti() {

  return [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

Here's [a working demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx-jSTpE2RaHjtf4poqu3WTNvz_5F_qLqmm2-NA1cCfHop5dmzD/exec), and [the script](https://script.google.com/d/1xErlZjF1sYR-_UiS-vIwUTtl2ABqdsVUhQOlmFYNwTjgi0i4Uau6_xbR/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can simply return the Array from your Server Side function and use in your client side Javascript directly as you are doing.

Relevant documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values

**Debug your client-side Javascript with the Developer Tools of your browser.**

Some guesses:

Your problem is likely to do with the way you are accessing the array on the Client side, perhaps `if(arry[i][0] == x)` is never matching, or your reference to index 1 instead of 0 is incorrect on line `var a = arry[i][1];`

Also you are declaring variable "a" within the braces of the if, but then assigning it outside those braces, perhaps you mean:

```
for(i=0;i<arry.length;++i) 
{
   if(arry[i][0] == x)   
   {
      var a = arry[i][1];
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
   }
}
```

Comment: Now , I have tried declaring variable "a" as an global. still It was not working the way I expected.. if(arry[i][0] == x) , I was checking first elemnet  in the array and trying to print the second element in the 2D array var a = arry[i][1];

Comment: By the way , It was showing 404 error in the javascript console. Failed to load resource